# FromSqlRaw does not return all rows as SQL request

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework

I work with a Postgres database. In the database I have a view called `Statistic`.

A simple SQL query

```
select * 
from public."Statistic"
```

returns 3404 rows.

In my database context, I have appropriate entity which describes like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<StatisticEntity>()
           .HasKey(x => new {x.CompanyId, x.FullAccount, x.Year, x.Month});
    //...........
}
```

These four columns describe unique key for the table. Actually I have also tried to use `.HasNoKey()`, and there is no difference.

I try to execute this line of code

```
return await Context.Statistic
                    .FromSqlRaw($"select * from public.\"Statistic\" ")
                    .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

and this only return 3333 rows.

Absolute similar code executed on .NET 6 and .NET 4.8 projects with exactly the same results.

Any idea what could be happening here?

I have tried describe entity with and without key, `select *` vs `select [column name], [column name]` - the result is always the same: from code, it returns only 3333 rows instead of the 3404 in real data.

Even if I just run this code

```
var connection = Context.Database.GetDbConnection();
await connection.OpenAsync();

using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from \"Statistic\"";
    var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

it returns a result of 3333 - instead of 3404 that are stored in the database.

I have really no idea what is causing this ....

Comment: did you check connection string in the app?

Comment: Is the user's default schema `public`? because in the second query you are not specifying it. Side note: `connection ` is missing a `using`.

Comment: Did you try with SQL Server Management Studio?  Check connection string and make sure you are accessing the same database.

Comment: Hi, so first of all, that is PostgreSQL and yes, I have double check the connection string and I am working with the same database from SQL client and from code. Actually there are no other databases at all.

Comment: I have tried with public. and without public schema - the result is the same.

Comment: Can you try to query directly in ADO.NET in new console application?

Comment: I have tried with next simple code in net6 console application
                var dt = new DataTable();
                using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=...."))
                {
                    using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        comm.CommandText = "select * from public.\"Statistic\"";
                        var da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(comm);
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
and result was again only 3333 rows. It always ignore some specific rows but i see no reason

Comment: Can you try with other provider (like ODBC/JDBC)?

Comment: I have tried with ODBC connection and result the same

Comment: You can export the two result sets and compare to identify the missing. Maybe this give you a hint.

Comment: I have tried - there is nothing common in the records which are missinng

Comment: What is the tool you use to see 3404?